# Flat-Style Div arrangement issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a webpage what has 4 full-width divs that have information vertically centered within them. Sort of like these:
http://www.rokivo.com/

https://dribbble.com/shots/2582917-Klas-Ranking-Landing-Page

I have tried using 3 dividers to center the elements but I cannot make the divs line up like in the examples. Here is the basic code:

```
<div id="elem1">
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="middleDiv">
      <div id="content">
        <!-- Content Here-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="elem2">
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="middleDiv">
      <div id="content2">
        <!-- Content Here-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


outerDiv {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
middleDiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: please provide relevant css

Comment: Show us your css please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example out:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.c-full-one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #444444;
}
.c-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
.c-seg-one {
  width: 25%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.c-full-two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #F44466;
}
.c-full-three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #FF9233;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="c-full-one">
    <div class="c-inner">
      <div class="c-seg-one">

      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="c-full-two">
    <div class="c-inner">
      <div class="c-seg-one">

      </div>
      <div class="c-seg-one">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-full-three">
    <div class="c-inner">
      <div class="c-seg-one">

      </div>
      <div class="c-seg-one">

      </div>
      <div class="c-seg-one">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Made it right now, just for fun :)

You can play with those outer or inner divs as much as you like (style them to your needs) or create new ones. Simple html and css structure to do your thing. You don't need any additional bootstrap css or any other to make this simple layout.

I used the `display:flex;` css property with the combination of `align-items: center;` for the inner container layout (`.c-inner`) and the `margin: 0 auto;` property to properly center all inner container segments (`.c-seg-one`), boxes or whatever you wish to call those content divs.

Cheers!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways, here's a few all of which work with this html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
</div>
```

All three examples in codepen: http://codepen.io/ijmccallum/pen/RaGjOZ

### Option 1: Flexbox

if you're only supporting modern browsers (ie9+ I think) this is the way to go, it's easy, simple and gives you a load of options to play with. I've written an article about how it works if anyone's interested: http://delphicdigital.com/blog/css-layout-techniques-part-2  (shameless self plug!)

```
.row { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-height:50px; 
  background: #eee;
}

.column {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### Option 2: `display:table;`

You could use an actual table but support for CSS Tables is awesome so older browsers will support this but you'll have to do some media query stuff to deal with switching down to 2 or 1 columns for smaller screens.

same html

```
.row { 
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:50px; 
  background: #eee;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### Option 3: Inline block, with a wee hack

the :before element lets us set the height of the row and use vertical-align to do vertical centering. Like CSS Tables this too has amazing support, plus it breaks onto new lines for smaller screens which is a nice plus.

```
.row { 
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

.row:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1px;
  height: 50px;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.child {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: table-row;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="child" style="background-color: red;">section 1</div>
    <div class="child" style="background-color: green;">section 2</div>
    <div class="child" style="background-color: blue;">section 3</div>
    <div class="child" style="background-color: orange;">section 4</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first website "Rokivo" is using Bootstrap. You can easily do this by using `.row` class of the Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Section 1 Starts --> 

      <div id="section1" class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
             <h2>Contact Me</h2>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Section 2 Starts -->           

      <div id="section2" class="row">
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Section 3 Starts -->  

      <div id="section3" class="row">
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Section 4 Starts -->          

      <div id="section4" class="row">
        ...
      </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Here is the link of example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/